# Charging Power Banks from Electric Car Charging Stations (DIY, LiFePO₄)

Tags: power, battery-charging, lithium-ion, automotive

Is it possible to charge my own Lithium-Ion Battery Bank from pay-to-use Electric Car charge stations?

I’m traveling in an (ICE-powered) caravan. I have a 0.7 kWh Lithium-Ion Battery Bank and a 100 W solar panel mounted to the roof of the vehicle. I don’t have space on the roof for another solar panel.

The battery bank has enough power to last me about 2-4 days (when also charging from the sun). The solar panel helps, but it inputs less power to the bank than I use each day. Therefore, I’m looking for a way to charge my caravan’s power wall battery bank about twice per week.

The power wall isn’t exactly portable; it’s very heavy, so I can’t bring it into a cafe. Hotels and campgrounds are too expensive.

I pass a lot of electric car charging stations, and I was wondering: can I connect it to a transformer that decreases the voltage and amps to my needs for charging my 0.7 kW power wall in my caravan?

My power wall can charge over AC 240V up to 10A. It can also charge over DC up to 25V, 12A.

Comment: See also https://secondlifestorage.com/index.php?threads/charge-battery-pack-with-ev-car-charger.8702/

Comment: See also http://www.analogevse.xyz/

Comment: See also https://www.openevse.com/

Comment: Why not charge from the ICE? Split-charge systems are common. Or fit a second alternator - that is another option done in some cases. Why are you so short of roof space? is this a tiny caravan? What about hanging a panel on the side? just park that side facing the sun :) or have it mountable on either side.

Comment: See also https://www.instructables.com/Type2-Mennekes-to-3-230V-Sockets-under-Constructio/

Answer (score 1):

It is not very practical to charge such a small battery from an EV charging station.

If your battery is only 0.7kWh the normal charging power to charge in four hours would be about 200W. I'm surprised that it would charge at 2.4kW, that would charge it in only 20 minutes.

If you do want to mimic a car you would need to provide the appropriate connector and emulate the vehicle side of the J1772 protocol.

[J1772 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAE_J1772).

I would suggest looking into charging from your vehicle or into being more creative about additional photovoltaic panels - maybe one or two that you only deploy when you need to charge. You would normally keep them in the caravan.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the charging station ratings.

The distinction between these three levels is the input voltage,
Level 1 uses 110/120 volts,
Level 2 uses 208/240 volts and
DC fast chargers use between 200 and 600 volts.

Comment: Level 1 and Level 2 are AC?

Comment: Yes of course but you need matching connectors